# can't open file 'import.py' :[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

Down below is my code my why i don't know their is a problem in it can someone help me out

THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE

python3: can't open file 'import.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

```
from cs50 import SQL
from sys import argv
import csv

# checking if code is executed properly else exit
if len(argv) < 2:
    print("usage error, import.py characters.csv")
    exit(1)
# Open the database for later reuse
db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

def division_title(initial):
    n = initial.split()
    if len(n) == 3:
     return n
    else:
        [n[0],None,n[1]]

with open(argv[1]) as csvfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        n = division_title(row["name"])
        db.execute("INSERT INTO student VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            n[0],n[1],n[2],row["house"],row["birth"]
        )
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this code?  It sounds to me like the Python interpreter isn't able to read your script file, and so it isn't even getting to the point where it matters what your code looks like.

Comment: Have you made sure that you have execute permissions on the python script? That could be the reason why the interpreter can't open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to go to your program's directory first
2. start with "python" and followed by your program's name

You may see my program in the pic below

[image: Click here to see]

I hope you find it usefull

Comment: it works i was so stupid i just forgot BUT THANKS ||